# Mongodb driver cannot determine the spring version

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, reflection

Forgive my ignorance, I am a newbie to Spring, MongoDB and reflections. I recently started working on a project, where I started facing this issue. Please help.

In package org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert;

There is a code snippet :-
public class DefaultDbRefResolver implements DbRefResolver {

```
private static final boolean IS_SPRING_4_OR_BETTER = SpringVersion.getVersion().startsWith("4");
```

..............
....................
..........
}

As per http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/SpringVersion.html

"Class that exposes the Spring version. Fetches the "Implementation-Version" manifest attribute from the jar file.
Note that some ClassLoaders do not expose the package metadata, hence this class might not be able to determine the Spring version in all environments. Consider using a reflection-based check instead: For example, checking for the presence of a specific Spring 2.0 method that you intend to call."

In my case MongoDB is unable to get Spring Version from SpringVersion.getVersion() call. Is there any fix available for this issue ? If not can someone please help me in referring to some class/functionality which is only present in RELEASE 4.0.5 so that I can find out version using reflection.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Why do you want to get the spring version?

Comment: @vmr Basically MongoDB library is trying to get SpringVersion, by making call to SpringVersion.getVersion(), and in some env this call is failing as per the spring docs due to classloader not exposing package metadata